# how get only src value of image in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have this value in image tag

I am using jqgrid and when I call

```
$('#testGridList').jqGrid ('getCell', id, 'pic');
```

This return

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/myApp/DownloadFile?type=THU_IMG&amp;id=409" height="70" width="90" class="example1tooltip" style="cursor:pointer" alt="photo" title="View Org photo" onclick="getUxx()">
```

How do I get only `src` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `attr()` as shown :-

```
var gridcell = $('#testGridList').jqGrid ('getCell', id, 'pic');
var imgsrc = $(gridcell).attr("src");
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/n0cfdxup/3/)

Comment: .getAttribute("src")  is not working. "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jqGrid(...).getAttribute is not a function"

Comment: @iTech..happy to help you..;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get src value like following.

```
var src = $('#testGridList').jqGrid ('getCell', id, 'pic').src;
```